# How to get this in Prototype function in React.component

Tags: reactjs, components

For Example ,i need to get Component object by 'this',but 'this' is undefined

component:

```
 <Menu onClick ={()=>this.MenuNavigate()}/>
```

protoTypeFunction:

```
React.Component.prototype.MenuNavigate = (e) => {
    // let url = e.item.props["data-url"]
    console.log(this)->undefined
}
```

How to get 'this' ?

i think all components extends React.Component, so i want to use function in all components what extends React.Component,for i don't need to wirte once more

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're trying to extend the React.Component, I wouldn't advice on messing up with the React.Component class, I would create my own base class like this:

```
class BaseComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.MenuNavigate = this.MenuNavigate.bind(this);
  }

  MenuNavigate(e) {
    console.log(this);
  }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
class Demo extends BaseComponent {
  render() {
    return <Menu onClick={this.MenuNavigate} />;
  }
}
```

Comment: i know this way to get  'this ', but i think all components extends React.Component, so i want to use function in all components what extends React.Component,for i don't need to wirte once more.

Comment: i got an excellent way to solve this ; but your solution also works;
here is my solution:

use ES7 Syn;

::this.MenuNavigate

this means "this.MenuNavigate.bind(this)" so that i can get current component object

Answer (score 5):

`this` is undefined because you have used arrow function which has lexically scoped `this`, i.e. it's bound to the context in which it was defined, not to the object it is being called on.

Using a function expression solves the issue:

```
React.Component.prototype.MenuNavigate = function(e){
    console.log(this);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/70670/

But I wouldn't go this route. What @Canastro suggest in the other answer is a good approach, another way could be a Higher Order Component which can wrap around your components and provide the MenuNavigat functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Arrow functions don't have `this`. You should use the traditional `function() {...}`.
But even then, I don't recommend messing with the React.component class or any other 3rd part or external class/object.